# How to read txt file and divide line by line and words by words using strtok and pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

I want read data 5 lines to final line.

I've already done line by line using `strtok` function and I will use `strtok` but didn't work.

`ptr21 result and`ptr` is same: what should I do?
my goal is struct -> 202001 ~ 167~236

Math.txt:

```
course name : Mathematics
Instructor : Mannan

ID  NAME    MID PROJECT FINAL   TOTAL
202001  s1  46  54  67  167
202002  s2  87  93  88  268
202004  s4  26  48  56  130
202006  s6  93  89  90  272
202007  s7  65  75  80  220
202008  s8  58  49  43  150
202010  s10 85  78  76  239
202012  s12 76  85  81  242
202013  s13 54  74  69  197
202014  s14 73  79  84  236
```

My code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define STRING_SIZE 256

#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

struct test_result { 
    int ID; 
    char NAME[10]; 
    int MID; 
    int PROJECT; 
    int FINAL; 
    int TOTAL; 
    float numeric; 
}; 

int num_students = 0; 

int main(void) {
    system("Cls");
    char answertype;
    FILE* f1= NULL;
    FILE* f2 = NULL;
    FILE* f3 = NULL;
    printf("\n\n\n");
    f1 = fopen("Math.txt", "r");
    f2 = fopen("Science.txt", "r");

    int linecount = 1;
    if (f1 != NULL)
    {
        int size;
        char *buffer;
        fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END);   
        size = ftell(f1);//size of buffer
        buffer = malloc(size + 1);
        fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_SET);  

        while (!feof(f2))
        {
            fgets(buffer, 34, f2);
            linecount++;
            char* ptr= strtok(buffer, " ");
            while (ptr != NULL && linecount > 5)//3 instruct 2 subject
            {
                if (ptr != "course")
                {
                    //printf(" %s", ptr);

                    struct test_result p1;
                    char* ptr2 = strtok(ptr, " ");
                    while (ptr2 != NULL)            
                    {
                        printf("%s", ptr2);          
                        ptr2 = strtok(NULL, " ");      
                    }
                    ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
                }   
            }
        }
        free(buffer);
        fclose(f1);
        fclose(f2);
        fclose(f3);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: t some miss in first line #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  
#define STRING_SIZE 256
#include <stdio.h>   
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
struct test_result
{
 int ID;
 char NAME[10];
 int MID;
 int PROJECT;
 int FINAL;
 int TOTAL;
 float numeric;
};
int num_students = 0;
int main(void)
{

Comment: You can add your corrections directly in the question by clicking `edit` (better: it is recommended) ;)

Comment: Math.txtcourse name : Mathematics
Instructor : Mannan

ID NAME  MID PROJECT FINAL TOTAL
202001 s1 46 54 67 167
202002 s2 87 93 88 268
202004 s4 26 48 56 130
202006 s6 93 89 90 272
202007 s7 65 75 80 220
202008 s8 58 49 43 150
202010 s10 85 78 76 239
202012 s12 76 85 81 242
202013 s13 54 74 69 197
202014 s14 73 79 84 236

Comment: Please add the data to the question itself with the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62349528/edit). May I also suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I notice that you do `ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");` *after* `strtok` has already returned `NULL` in the loop above. Did you want that? Note that you can't use `strtok` on two different strings at the same time.  You need the reentrant version `strtok_r`.

Comment: to Weather Vane i want txt file divid line by line and word by word if in that code erase of ptr2 output is ID name mid pj final and total  and this data i want use

Comment: You calculate the size of `Math.h`, for some reason you use it to determine the size of `buffer`, but later you write in it at most 35 chars with `fgets(buffer, 34, f2);`. Did you mean `fgets(buffer, size, f2);`?

Comment: Note that you can't use `strtok` on two different strings at the same time. You need the reentrant version `strtok_r`. It is the same string, but it seems as if you want `ptr` and `ptr2` to work independently. Note too that in C you cannot compare strings like: `if (ptr != "course")` but you must use `strcmp`.

Comment: Another note: as I already said you calculate the size of `Math.h` (pointer `f1`), and apparently it is the one which matter (as you posted its contents). But instead you keep reading `f2` that is related to `Science.txt`. Is it what you want?

Comment: size of math and science txt is same and also change  fgets(buffer, 34, f2); >fgets(buffer, size, f2); i use  windows visual studio and i can't use strtok_r so i will use strtok_s  why if (ptr != "course") is my edit mistake

Comment: So their size is the same. Is it the same also for its contents?

Comment: yes    if (ptr != "NULL")
     {
       //printf("%s", ptr);
      
       //struct test_result p1;
       char* ptr2=NULL;
       char *context=NULL;
       ptr2 = strtok_s(ptr, " ", &context);
       while (ptr2 != NULL)            
      {
        printf("%s", ptr2);
       ptr2 = strtok_s(NULL, " ",&context);

       
      }
      ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
     } i edit as much as i can not change how can i use strtok_s is this right?